# How to create a spinner field with symfony form?

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, symfony4

I want to have a spinner in my symfony form:

```
<input type="number" />
```

It seems symfony does not have such form field type? and it seems their custom form field type is not for this job? https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 4.3 you can use the [NumberType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html) and set the [html5](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#html5) option to true so that the output is a "input type number".